# Incorrect output of findCorrelation (caret package)

Tags: r, matrix, r-caret

I use 'findCorrelation' function of caret package to define factors with correlation equal or below cutoff (threshold) set. My script is as follows:

```
library (caret)
set.seed(123)
#make a matrix to calculate correlation
data<-as.matrix(data.frame(x=rnorm(1:1000),y=rnorm(1:1000),z=rnorm(1:1000),w=rnorm(1:1000)))
#calculate correlation
df2 <- cor(data)
hc <- findCorrelation(as.matrix(df2), cutoff=0.05) # putt any value as a "cutoff"
hc <- sort(hc)
print(df2)
print(df2[-hc,-hc])
```

df2 output (all factors):
    print(df2)

> ```
>       x            y           z            w
> ```
>
> x  1.00000000  0.086479441 -0.01932954 -0.002994710
>   y  0.08647944  1.000000000  0.02650333 -0.007029076
>   z -0.01932954  0.026503334  1.00000000  0.050560850
>   w -0.00299471 -0.007029076  0.05056085  1.000000000

df2 with applied cutoff of 0.05:

```
print(df2[-hc,-hc])
```

> ```
>       x           w
> ```
>
> x  1.00000000 -0.00299471
>   w -0.00299471  1.00000000

But if I apply the cutoff=0.1, for instance, I will have a zero matrix instead of the list of all factors below the cutoff:

```
hc <- findCorrelation(as.matrix(df2), cutoff=0.1) 
hc <- sort(hc)
print(df2[-hc,-hc])
```

The df2 output with cutoff=0.1:

> <0 x 0 matrix>

I have run other examples from my business cases and it is appeared to have at least one factor above the cutoff value to generate the matrix of factors below cutoff.
Otherwise, zero matrix is generated.

I have dived into the script of 'findCorrelation' but it worked well. Maybe the script is not presumed to handle such a case.

So I would be grateful for your hints how to tackle the issue.

**UPDATE of 07/03/16:**
Due to usefull answer of @topepo I have revised the script:

the part to be replaced:

```
print(df2[-hc,-hc])
```

with:

```
if(length(hc)==0){
  print(df2)
}else{
  print(df2[-hc,-hc])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug.

In `?findCorrelation`, it describes the value returned as

> A vector of indices denoting the columns to remove (when `names = TRUE`) otherwise a vector of column names. If no correlations meet the criteria, `integer(0)` is returned.

The issue that you are seeing results because you need to make sure that the subsetting vector has elements to it via something like

`if(length(hc) > 0) df2 <- df2[-hc, -hc]`

Any zero length integer would produce this issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have review my reproducible script and made the correct amendments